# NHibernate - create a complex index from hbm file

Tags: nhibernate

I am creating my tables and indexes from the NHibernate mappings.

For example, I create the LastName index as follows:

```
  <property name="LastName" column="LastName" type="String" length="50"  not-null="true" index="IDX_Patient_Lastname"/>
```

I would like to create a complex index, so that for example LastName and FirstName are generated as one index. Is this possible in NHibernate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assign same index name to FirstName :

```
<property name="LastName" column="LastName" type="String" length="50"  not-null="true" index="IDX_Patient_Lastname"/>
<property name="FirstName" column="FirstName" type="String" length="50"  not-null="true" index="IDX_Patient_Lastname"/>
```

Comment: Works just great. Looked through all the NHibernate documentation and couldn't find a hint to the solution.

Comment: By the way, do you know how to give the primary key a nice name. I use the following:     <id name="Id" type="Guid">
                       <generator class="guid.comb"/>
                      </id>                                      This produces an ugly index name (PK__Pacijent__3214EC077C792BF3). Tried to add index to the key, but it isn't supported

Comment: Fixed my comment. I accidentally pressed the enter key, so the comment was only half way done. I'd like a name like PK_Patient and not the autogenerated PK__Pacijent__3214EC077C792BF3.

Comment: I don't think it is supported. Tried to do it a few times, but I learned to live with the ugly PK name

Comment: OK, thanks. I guess, I'll have to live with this too. If I come across a solution, I'll let you know.