# How can we have an index in my nhibernate mapping when table is created?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, indexing, mapping

I have a table in my database and I use NHibernate as data access layer. Now I want to modify my NHibernate Mappings for creating an index on my database.
Is it possible?

Notice that I don't want to create my tables from my model and my tables is created.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647534/nhibernate-create-a-complex-index-from-hbm-file

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about it's current state, but Ayende wrote something about it on his blog: http://nhibernate.hibernatingrhinos.com/14/create-and-update-database-schema

I don't have any experience with it though, because we use our own custom built database migration tools, but perhaps it works for you?